# How to contribute to spring?

Tags: spring

I have gone through the process (code fork, JIRA account, etc.) to contribute to spring-related projects from GitHub.

But I am not sure how to assign a JIRA issue to myself because I don't see any such option on the [JIRA instance](http://jira.spring.io).

Can someone please guide me as I would like to start contributing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Contributing to a spring-related issue is quite easy. For the [spring framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) there is a [contributing page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) on the github repository.

Other spring-related projects have a similar setup so check the project you are interested in for more information.

As for assigning issues, it is reserved to the team as every pull request (patch) is first reviewed before being applied. If you are willing to work on an issue, just say so by adding a comment and we'll assist you.

Comment: Thanks Stephane. Will pick up a JIRA (bug) to start with by adding my comment in the JIRA.